# How can I obtain a list of domains for a page/user/app using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to use Facebook's Graph API to grab a user's insights data, and display it in an admin panel for them, as a part of their custom CMS.

There are a few steps to my Facebook integration:
1. Authenticate
2. Get a list of pages, applications, and domains for the user
3. Get insights data for each page, application and domain

All of the above are working, but I can't find a way to list all the domains a user has.  I'm using https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts to get the list of accounts for the user.  This is returning all the Pages and Applications, but no Domains.

I have looked all over Facebook's docs, and can't find any reference to a method for retrieving a list.

I have tried https://graph.facebook.com/domains, https://graph.facebook.com/me/domains, https://graph.facebook.com/domain, and https://graph.facebook.com/me/domain - to no avail. https://graph.facebook.com/domain and https://graph.facebook.com/domains are valid, but are only useful if you know the domain.

So, the question: Is there a way to obtain a list of domains for a user using the Graph API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this Graph API call:  `https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT domain_name, domain_id FROM domain WHERE domain_id in ( SELECT domain_id FROM domain_admin WHERE owner_id=me())&access_token=VALIDUSERACCESSTOKENOFTHEOWNEROFTHEDOMAIN`

Comment: This works perfectly - thank you. For those that are interested, to get all the domains associated with all the user's accounts: 1. access me/accounts 2. iterate over the results, and for each account (either a page or an app), run DMCS's fql after replacing `owner_id=me()` with `owner_id=ACCOUNTID_RETURNED_FROM_ME/ACCOUNTS`.

Comment: Whew!  I'm glad that worked.  I coded it up blindly and ran it against my account and got back nothing.  But the syntax looked correct, so I posted it.